# Iterating over nested list and extracting the items

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the below two list having the data as shown below

the very first list as shown below

storeIdList

```
 0 = "1"
 1 = "10"
 2 = "12"
 3 = "44"
```

the second list data is coming is of orderList

```
 0  ="[1]"
 1  ="[]"
 2  ="[]"
 3= "[46,47]"
```

so basically each store has certain orders and as shown store 44 has two orders that is 46 and 47
so they are declared as shown below of type string

```
 List<String> storeIdList
 List<String> orderList
```

Now basically I want to iterate over a storeList first and from within that store I want to extract the orders with in that store if orders are there for that particular store , for example store 44 has two orders 46 and 47 and store 10 has no orders at all,

so to achieve this I have used two nested for loops

```
for (int i=0 ; i<storeIdList.size();i++)
 { 
   for (int j=0 ; j<orderList.size();j++)
   {
     // do buisness logic
   }
  }
```

Now the issue is that for store 44 , I am not able to extract both independently that is 46 and 47 please advise how can i extract th orders indepednetly with in the storeId loop

Comment: "I am not able to extract both independently that is 46 and 47" can you plz explain on that. I couldn't understand what you want there.

Comment: @aatwork well for store 44 i want to extract order no 46 and 47 as i want to pass both these orders into further method processing

Comment: Can you change the data structure from List<String> to something else? Or you don't have control on that?

Comment: Do you want to convert the `String` `"[46,47]"` into the `int` array `[46, 47]` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would not use such data structure, you could use `Map<String, List<String>>` for example, where key is a store id and value is a list of orders. However, if you are forced to keep the provided structure, you could extract the orders in the following way:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<storeIdList.size();i++) {
     String storeId = storeIdList.get(i);
     String orders = orderList.get(i);
}
```

But you should ensure that orderList has the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the corresponding string in `orderList` using `orderList.get(storeIdList.indexOf(storeId))` and then split it on `,\s*` after replacing `[` and `]` with `""`, and finally return the resulting `String[]`.

**Note:** I have also provided you with a variant of the functions which returns `List<String>`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> storeIdList = List.of("1", "10", "12", "44");
        List<String> orderList = List.of("[1]", "[]", "[]", "[46,47]");
        System.out.println(storeIdList);
        System.out.println(orderList);

        // Get orderIds for storeId, 44
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getOrderIdArray(storeIdList, orderList, "44")));
        System.out.println(getOrderIdList(storeIdList, orderList, "44"));
    }

    static String[] getOrderIdArray(List<String> storeIdList, List<String> orderList, String storeId) {
        return orderList.get(storeIdList.indexOf(storeId))
                        .replace("[", "")
                        .replace("]", "")
                        .split(",\\s*");
    }

    static List<String> getOrderIdList(List<String> storeIdList, List<String> orderList, String storeId) {
        return Arrays.asList(orderList.get(storeIdList.indexOf(storeId))
                                        .replace("[", "")
                                        .replace("]", "")
                                        .split(",\\s*")
                            );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 10, 12, 44]
[[1], [], [], [46,47]]
[46, 47]
[46, 47]
```

**Explanation of the regex, `,\s*` at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1ubZIt/1):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample lists, there are corresponding store elements and order elements. In other words, the first element of `orderList` are the orders for the first element of `storeIdList`. And you want to extract all the orders for each store.

Consider the following.

```java
List<String> storeIdList = List.of("1", "10", "12", "44");
List<String> orderList = List.of("[1]", "[]", "[]", "[46,47]");
for (int i = 0; i < storeIdList.size(); i++) {
    String order = orderList.get(i).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    if (order.length() > 0) {
        String[] orders = order.split(",");
        System.out.printf("Store %s orders: %s%n",
                          storeIdList.get(i),
                          java.util.Arrays.toString(orders));
    }
}
```

First I remove the brackets from the string containing the orders and then I split the resulting string on each comma and thus I get an array where each array element is a single order.

Then you can perform your business logic on the array `orders`.

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Store 1 orders: [1]
Store 44 orders: [46, 47]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i< storeIdList.size() ; i++){
        String[] orderIds = orderIdList.get(i).split(",");
        for(int j = 0; j< orderIds.length ; j++){
            System.out.println("Store Id : "+ i + ", Order Id : " j);
        }
   }
```

Orderlist can have multiple list, You need to split it to retrieve individually